# HTML Can't scroll down on Profile

Tags: html, text, scroll, scrollbar, profile

Hi there so I've been searching this site for a solid hour looking for an answer but the coding for this profile is too complicated for me. There's more to see farther down, but the code is stopping the page from scrolling. Any way I can fix this?

http://www.aniroleplay.com/view_profile.php?member_id=153982

Comment: there seem to be some elementss with `position: fixed;`. That forces a element to stay at the exact position of the browser window. You should take a look into that.

Comment: PS: I would highly recommend looking into another way to write your code. Styling with tables. Almost every element I checked was absolute positioned. On my screen the page is way to the left and very small (if the site is supposed to be for medium sized screens, alright then). And rightclicking is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to view the entire page do this (if using Google Chrome):

1. Open Dev tools in your browser (press F12).
2. Click the magnifying glass in the top left corner of the tools.
3. Hover just to the left of where the content is and click when "div.fat" is highlighted.
4. Scroll to the top of the section on the right with the "Styles" tab selected and deselect position:fixed.
5. Repeat steps 4 and 5 but for "div.top".

If you get stuck just ask.